# Python Packet Sniffer and Sockets for Noobs

Tags: python, windows, sockets, runtime-error, sniffer

So I have some questions about sockets and sniffer programming...
I've *just started programming* and have a project where I would like to use information that is sent across my network.

I tried watching several videos on youtube that talk about this process a little, and tried to find better material to research it further, but I haven't been able to find a source that makes sense to me.

The code I included came from a video on youtube and seemed to make sense as they explained it, but I guess he might have been using Linux or something else because Windows did not support AF_PACKET.  After some research I found that people use AF_INET, but I got the error:

OSError: [WinError 10043] The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists

Is there a place or a way someone might be able to explain sockets a little bit for me?  I don't plan to use windows for the final version of this project, and I also plan to modify it for bluetooth in the future, so I would like to learn the reasoning behind things if I can find a way to do that.

`
    import socket
    import struct
    import textwrap

```
def main():
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
        while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)
        print('\nEthernet Frame:')
        print('Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data[:14]))


#unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
     dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])
     return get_mac_addr(dest_mac), get_mac_addr(src_mac), socket.htons(proto), data[14:]

#Get Mac Address
def get_mac_addr(bytes_addr):
    bytes_str = map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr)
    return ':'.join(bytes_str).upper()

main()
```

`

Comment: Did you run this as administrator?

Comment: Ok, I saw something about this... And I think I tried a version of this. What I tried was running it in python after I enabled run as administrator in compatibility in properties... But I didn't try anything through command @kichik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSes on which you use a socket for packet sniffing are:

1. Linux
2. Irix

Windows is not on that list (neither are anything with "BSD" in the name, OS X, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, etc.).  Linux and Irix both happen to use sockets to do sniffing, but that's just their choice (and they didn't choose the same *type* of socket, they just happened to choose sockets).

If you want to write a sniffer, you're probably best advised to use a wrapper around libpcap/WinPcap, and let them deal with the painful details of the way packet sniffing is done on a particular operating system. Wrappers for Python include [pylibpcap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/) and [pcapy](http://www.coresecurity.com/corelabs-research/open-source-tools/pcapy); I don't know whether either of them work on Windows with WinPcap.

(Note that you are not guaranteed to get Ethernet headers on sniffed packets; you should call `pcap_datalink()`, or whatever the wrapper's equivalent is, and check its return value - if it's not `DLT_EN10MB`, or the wrapper's equivalent, you won't be getting Ethernet headers.)

`AF_INET` raw sockets, on *any* platform, aren't going to give you Ethernet headers. I don't know *what* you'll get with a protocol argument of 3 - 3 is the Internet protocol number for GGP, as per [RFC 823](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc823) Appendix A, and that protocol is ancient and not used as far as I know; you'll probably end up with a socket on which you can send GGP packets and from which you can receive GGP packets, for what that's worth (which is not much).  (Also, the arguments to the `socket()` call in C are in host byte order, and Python probably works the same, so you probably don't want that `socket.ntohs()` in there, not that it'll make a difference.)

Comment: Awesome! That's much more direct information than I have been able to find anywhere else. I saw some things about WinPcap and some of the other options, but no real explanation about reasoning to use them. This should definitely help, for this specific project, I don't think I will need the headers, I just want to convert all the captures to hexcode, but I will definitely need it on the next version. So the datalink action tests for headers? @guyharris

Comment: `pcap_datalink()` returns a value indicating what headers are at the beginning of the packet; [here's a detailed list of possible values](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html).  If you're just converting to hex, do it byte-by-byte, not treating different bytes differently - don't assume, for example, that the packet begins with two 6-byte MAC addresses, for example.

Comment: Ok, last question... I promise! Lol, is there a good resource to grab just a little more basic information about network interface? I have a whopping weeks worth of Google experience with programming and with networking... @guyharris

Comment: What sort of information are you looking for?  There are a lot of types of information, so there are different resources for different information.

Comment: Right, that was pretty broad. If you have any ideas for the basics of sockets and device communication, that would be great! I feel like those are the most difficult to find information about. @guyharris

Comment: I don't know what's a good tutorial; try searching around the Web and seeing what shows up.